# How do I change the default color of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to know how to change the color from the second picture to the first one
I'm new to ggplot2 and still learning atm

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mpg)
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
          geom_bar(
            mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = clarity),
            position = "dodge"
          )
```

I thought I would get many colors as the first pic but I got colors in the second one.[First pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSiFt.jpg)
[Second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zL0F.jpg)

Comment: I think those colors are from the viridis palette. Add ```+ scale_fill_viridis_d()``` to your code. FYI, you can change the background color by using for example ```+theme_bw()```

Comment: This website showing ```brewer``` palettes is also very helpful in selecting a palette which suits your data https://colorbrewer2.org/

Comment: ADding to @maarvd, if your not just looking for changing the colours of the data, but also the plot window itself (including axis) you are looking for themes. The [`ggthemes`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) package has a large set of varied standard themes that can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colour using various methods. Here are a couple of examples:

1. You can specify manual colours using codes from a page like [this](https://i.redd.it/ns6qgxqwfzp11.png) and using `scale_fill_manual`

```
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut))+
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", aes(fill = clarity))+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0CFCA0", "#A54408", "#E53975", "#7FB0FF", 
                                   "#4ACC0A", "#51397F", "#FFC059", "#062C7F"))
```

Which creates this: [Manual colours - excuse the choices, they were at random](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgbbI.png)

[This page](https://statisticsglobe.com/identify-default-color-palette-names-of-ggplot2-in-r) has the codes from the `ggplot2` default colours you showed in yout first picture.

2. As maarvd mentioned above you could use `RColorBrewer`

```
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut))+
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", aes(fill = clarity))+
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu")
```

Which creates this: [Brewer colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeNrM.png)